# Arithmetic Sequences on Prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

> It is known that $a_1, a_2,$...$, a_{50}$ is an arithmetic sequence with common difference $d$, and $a_i (i=1, 2, ..., 50)$ are primes. If $a_1>50$, prove that $d>600,000,000,000,000,000.$

Honestly I have completely no idea how to solve this question. I don't even know how $6*10^{17}$ is derived from. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The link you provided only says that $a_i>a_j$ if $i>j$, but does not state that the difference between two consecutive terms of the sequence is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix any prime $p<50$, and consider the sequence mod $p$. Notice that none of the terms (say $a$) can be equal to $0$, because otherwise $p\mid a$. But if $p\nmid d$, the sequence will eventually be $0$ mod $p$. (within the first 50 terms). Hence $p\mid d$ for all primes less than 50.

If you multiply all the primes out, you get around $6.15\times10^{17}$ which is large enough.

Comment: "But if p∤d, the sequence will eventually be 0 mod p."
Why is this so?

Comment: $a,a+d,a+2d,\ldots,a+(p-1)d$ are all distinct mod $p$. If any two of them were equal, say $a+id\equiv a+jd$, then $id\equiv jd\implies p\mid d(j-i)$. But $p$ doesn't divide either of the two, and thus no two of them are equal.